# R plot numbers of factor levels having n, n+1, .... counts

Tags: r, plot

I have a very large dataset (> 200000 lines) with 6 variables (only the first two shown)

```
>head(gt7)
      ChromKey  POS
    1     2447   25
    2     2447  183
    3    26341   75
    4    26341 2213
    5    26341 2617
    6    54011 1868
```

I have converted the Chromkey variable to a factor variable made up of > 55000 levels.

```
> gt7[1] <- lapply(gt7[1], factor)
> is.factor(gt7$ChromKey)
[1] TRUE
```

I can further make a table with counts of ChromKey levels

```
> table(gt7$ChromKey)

   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17 
  88   88   44   33   11   11   33   22  121   11   22   11   11   11   22   11   33 
  18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34 
  22   22   44   55   22   11   22   66   11   11   11   22   11   11   11  187   77 
  35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49   50   51 
  77   11   44   11   11   11   11   11   11   22   66   11   22   11   44   22   22 
... outut cropped
```

Which I can save in table format

```
> table <- table(gt7$ChromKey)
> head(table)

 1  2  3  4  5  6 
88 88 44 33 11 11
```

I would like to know whether is it possible to have a table (and histogram) of the number of levels with specific count numbers. From the example above, I would expect

```
  88  44  33  11
   2   1   1   2
```

I would very much appreciate any hint.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Voted-up but my reputation is too low to show it. Pablo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can apply `table` again on the output to get the frequency count of the frequency

```
table(table(gt7$ChromKey))
```